# True or false on two statements(about entire function)

Tags: complex-analysis

$f (z)$ is an entire function.

1. If $f (x)$ is bounded for all real x, then f is a constant function.
2. If | f (z)| → ∞ as |z| → ∞, then f is a polynomial.

Can you tell me how to judge these 2 statements?

Comment: What about $f(z)=\sin(z)$?

Comment: Thank you for your help in (1)

Comment: Do you know Casorati-Weierstrass?

Comment: @zhw. Thanks I have used Picard Great Theorem to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for (2): $r(z)/f(z)$ is bounded for a certain rational function $r(z)$

Comment: but $r(z)/f(z)$ may not be an entire function, so we cannot get $r(z)/f(z)=constant$.

Comment: After removing singularities by including appropriate factors in $r$, it is and we do.

Comment: But what if $f(z)$ has infinite zeros? Or how can you guarantee that $r(z)$ may not $\rightarrow \infty$ when $z \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: By assumption $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty$, so e.g. there must be some $R$ such that $|f(z)| > 1$ for $|z| > R$.  That means all the zeros are in the disk $\{z: |z| \le R\}$.  From that it's easy to show there are only finitely many zeros.

Comment: I have solved this problem from your initial Hint: the singularity at infinity is a pole and then transforming $\frac{1}{z}=w$ shows that w has a pole at w=0 and hence it can be written into $w=\sum_{n=-k}^0 a_n w^n$, which means $f(z)$ is a polynomial. Thanks for your help!